# Order axis when doing a bubble chart using plotly in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a bubble chart using plotly in R but the order of the axis appear to be somehow odd.

The output is as follows and you can see how the axis are not correct:

[image: BubbleChart]

The code that I'm using is as follows

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

file <- c("C://link//data.csv")
#dataSource <- read.csv(file, sep =",", header = TRUE)
dataSource <- read.table(file, header=T, sep=",")
dataSource <- na.omit(dataSource)

slope <- 1 
dataSource$size <- sqrt(dataSource$Y.1 * slope)
colors <- c('#4AC6B7', '#1972A4') #, '#965F8A', '#FF7070', '#C61951')

plot_ly(dataSource, 
        x = ~Y.1.vs.Y.2, 
        y = ~YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD, 
        color = ~BU, 
        size = ~size, 
        colors = colors, 
        type = 'scatter', 
        mode = 'markers', 
        sizes = c(min(dataSource$size), max(dataSource$size)),
        marker = list(symbol = 'circle', sizemode = 'diameter',
        line = list(width = 2, color = '#FFFFFF')),
        text = ~paste('Business Unit:', 
                      BU, '<br>Product:', 
                      Product, '<br>Y.1.vs.Y.2:', 
                      Y.1.vs.Y.2, '<br>YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD:', 
                      YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD)) %>%
        layout(title = 'Y.1.vs.Y.2 v. YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD',
                      xaxis = list(title = 'Y.1.vs.Y.2',
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                      zerolinewidth = 1,
                      ticklen = 5,
                      gridwidth = 2),
         yaxis = list(title = 'YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD',
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                      zerolinewidth = 1,
                      ticklen = 5,
                      gridwith = 2),
         paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)',
         plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)')
```

The data is as follows:

```
structure(list(BU = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("B", "D"), class = "factor"), Product = structure(c(4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 11L, 12L, 13L), .Label = c("ADT", "BHL", "CEX", "CMX", "CTL", "HTH", "MTL", "SSL", "TLS", "UTV", "WEX", "WLD", "WMX"), class = "factor"), Y.2 = c(4065L, 499L, 20L, 5491L, 781L, 53L, 34L, 1338L, 557L, 428L, 310L, 31L), Y.1 = c(4403L, 550L, 28L, 5225L, 871L, 46L, 22L, 1289L, 602L, 426L, 318L, 37L), Y.1.YTD = c(4403L, 550L, 28L, 5225L, 871L, 46L, 22L, 1289L, 602L, 426L, 318L, 37L), YTD = c(5026L, 503L, 29L, 3975L, 876L, 40L, 62L, 1395L, 717L, 423L, 277L, 35L), Y.1.vs.Y.2 = structure(c(12L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 6L, 10L, 9L), .Label = c("-13%", "-35%", "-4%", "-5%", "-76%", "0%", "10%", "12%", "19%", "3%", "40%", "8%"), class = "factor"), YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD = structure(c(8L, 5L, 11L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("-1%", "-13%", "-24%", "-5%", "-9%", "0%", "1%", "14%", "182%", "19%", "4%", "8%"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("BU", "Product", "Y.2", "Y.1", "Y.1.YTD", "YTD", "Y.1.vs.Y.2", "YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD"), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(c(1L, 7L, 12L), .Names = c("1", "7", "12"), class = "omit"))
```

Any ideas on how can I order the axis properly?

Thanks

Comment: Have you solved this yet? I think you just need to change the order of your factor levels.

Comment: How do yo order the factors? I tried adding the following before the plot_ly function, but it didn't work: dataSource <- dataSource[order(dataSource$YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD), ]

Comment: I tried also the following, but it doesn't work: dataSource$YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD <- factor(dataSource$YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD, levels = rev(unique(dataSource$YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD)), ordered=TRUE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to manipulate factor levels, but things can get a bit messy if you're not careful. You should familiarize yourself with `?levels` and `?factor`, as well as maybe `?reorder`, `?relevel`

In the meantime, try something like this

```
dataSource[[7]] <- factor(dataSource[[7]], levels = c("-76%", "-35%", "-13%", "-5%", "-4%", "0%", "3%", "8%", "10%", "12%", "19%", "40%"))
```

**Edit**

To consolidate my answer and comment...

This behaviour is caused because of the way factors are encoded. Your axes are strings and factor order is determined alphnumerically. So to change their order you have to specify it as above, or else code them numerically and give them the required names. There are many different ways to change them, in several packages. This answer provides a standard base R method for handling factors. For further info start with the manual pages I suggested.

As for it being "very manual", since factors are categorical (and therefore have a potentially arbitrary order), there is no way to automate their order unless you code them numerically in the desired order.

Comment: Thanks, that work and similarly for the other axix (dataSource[[8]]<- factor(dataSource[[8]], levels = c("-24%", "-13%", "-9%", "-5%", "-1%", "1%", "4%", "8%", "14%", "19%", "182%"))), but this seems to be a very manual process

Comment: I see. Then, converting the factors into numerical should sort the problem. Something like: dataSource <- as.data.frame(data.matrix(dataSource), stringsAsfactors = FALSE). Doing this I'm loosing the percentage information, so I will have to recalculate them, but might help to resolve the problem

Comment: I imagine that will present another issue - at the moment the axes intervals are not equally spaced - perhaps they should be? It depends on what you want to do I guess. But that would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above I've been able to resolve the issue. Find below the full code, which I hope might help other users:

```
    library(plotly)
    library(ggplot2)

    file <- c("C://link//data.csv")
    dataSource <- read.table(file, header=T, sep=",")
    dataSource <- na.omit(dataSource)

    # Additional code to format the input values and recalculate the percentages
    BUValues = dataSource$BU
    ProductValues = dataSource$Product
    dataSource <- as.data.frame(data.matrix(dataSource), stringsAsfactors = FALSE)
    dataSource$BU = BUValues
    dataSource$Product = ProductValues
    dataSource$Y.1.vs.Y.2 = round((dataSource$Y.1/dataSource$Y.2 -1)*100,2)
    dataSource$YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD = round((dataSource$YTD/dataSource$Y.1.YTD -1)*100,2)

    slope <- 1 
    dataSource$size <- sqrt(dataSource$Y.1 * slope)
    colors <- c('#4AC6B7', '#1972A4') #, '#965F8A', '#FF7070', '#C61951')

    plot_ly(dataSource, 
            x = ~Y.1.vs.Y.2, 
            y = ~YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD, 
            color = ~BU, 
            size = ~size, 
            colors = colors, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'markers', 
            sizes = c(min(dataSource$size), max(dataSource$size)),
            marker = list(symbol = 'circle', sizemode = 'diameter',
            line = list(width = 2, color = '#FFFFFF')),
            text = ~paste('Business Unit:', BU, 
                          '<br>Product:', Product, 
                          '<br>YoY:',Y.1.vs.Y.2, 
                          '<br>YTD:',YTD.vs.Y.1.YTD)) %>%
            layout(title = 'YoY vs YTD Performance',
                          xaxis = list(title = 'YoY Performance (%)',
                          gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                          zerolinewidth = 1,
                          ticklen = 5,
                          gridwidth = 2),
                          yaxis = list(title = 'YTD Performance (%)',
                          gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                          zerolinewidth = 1,
                          ticklen = 5,
                          gridwith = 2),
             paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)',
             plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)')
```